# Multiple value filtration from single column using like clause in Codeigniter Active Records

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, sql-like

I'm trying to `filter` column from `MySQL database` with `Codeigniter` `Active Records`. I'm passing values from drop-down list box and using that I want data to be filtered. When I'm selecting single value from different drop-down list, I get proper filtered result. But when I'm trying to filtered using multiple values from single drop-down, it give

> No matching records found

in `data-table`. For filtration I'm using `Like statement`.

**Here is my Model code:**

```
private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        //add custom filter here
        // if($this->input->post('startdate') && $this->input->post('enddate'))
        // {
        //  $this->db->where("'FUPdate' BETWEEN 'startdate' AND 'enddate'");
        // }
        if($this->input->post('area'))
        {
            $this->db->like('area_name', $this->input->post('area'));
        }
        if($this->input->post('cluster'))
        {
            $clustersID['cluster']=$this->input->post('cluster');
            if(!empty($clustersID['cluster'])){
              // Array contains values, everything ok
              $clusterString = implode(', ', $clustersID['cluster']);
            }

            if ($clusterString) {
                $this->db->like('cluster_name', $clusterString);
            } else {
                $this->db->or_like('cluster_name', $clusterString);
        }

        }
        if($this->input->post('timeframe'))
        {
            $this->db->like('timeframe_name', $this->input->post('timeframe'));
        }
        if($this->input->post('defect_status'))
        {
            $this->db->like('defect_status_name', $this->input->post('defect_status'));
        }
        if($this->input->post('startdate'))
        {
            $this->db->like('FUPdate', $this->input->post('startdate'));
        }
        if($this->input->post('enddate'))
        {
            $this->db->like('FUPdate', $this->input->post('enddate'));
        }

        $this->db->from($this->Property_Defect_View);
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->Property_Defect_search as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->Property_Defect_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->Property_Defect_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }
```

My question is, How can I pass array to like clause to filter data ?

In above I want to pick a multiple clusters to filter data. is it possible to use `AND operation` with Like `Statement`.

Comment: you should output your query and check against what you really want - nobody can forecast what you really want - after you execute your query - just put an `echo $this->db->last_query();` and take a look - after that - update your question with this query and define what you really want instead - then its easy to help you - otherwise its just a guessing game...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **$this->db->or_like()**

```
$this->db->like('cluster_name', 'clusterString'); 

if($this->input->post('timeframe'))
{
    $this->db->or_like('timeframe_name', $this->input->post('timeframe'));
}
if($this->input->post('defect_status'))
{
    $this->db->or_like('defect_status_name', $this->input->post('defect_status'));
}
if($this->input->post('startdate'))
{
    $this->db->or_like('FUPdate', $this->input->post('startdate'));
}
if($this->input->post('enddate'))
{
    $this->db->or_like('FUPdate', $this->input->post('enddate'));
}
```

Reference : [or_like()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: Even I'm trying like this: if($this->input->post('cluster'))
        {
         $clustersID['cluster']=$this->input->post('cluster');
         if(!empty($clustersID['cluster'])){
     // Array contains values, everything ok
     $clusterString = implode(', ', $clustersID['cluster']);
   }

            if ($clusterString) {
                $this->db->like('cluster_name', $clusterString);
            } else {
                $this->db->or_like('cluster_name', $clusterString);
            }
        }, but no output.

Comment: This is for looking multiple clusters in cluster column